# In App Billing Library doesn't provide the Updated PurchaseList after Consuming the Purchase Item?

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I am currently Implementing in App Purchase using In App Billing Library,

After Consuming the Purchased Item using method :

```
mBillingClient.consumeAsync(purchaseToken, new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsumeResponse(int responseCode, String purchaseToken) {
                    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Consumed Successfully..." + purchaseToken, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
```

when I open the app again and want to Retrieve the list of the Purchases List using the Method:

```
mBillingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(int responseCode, List<Purchase> purchasesList) {
            if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                purchases = purchasesList;
                retrieveItemList();
            }
        }
    });
```

It also provides me the Item which I have consumed in the list. So, help me to find what i'm doing wrong to get the updated purchase List.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use `queryPurchase` method instead of `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync` as below:

```
mBillingClient.queryPurchase(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(int responseCode, List<Purchase> purchasesList) {
        if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
            purchases = purchasesList;
            retrieveItemList();
        }
    }
});
```

Difference between both the method is that `queryPurchaseHistoryAync` will provide you the list of all the items you have purchased in your lifetime, even after the purchased item is used; while `queryPurchase` will provide you the list of currently purchased items.